# Discord.py - command ping has not been defined even when i have defined it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was following a tutorial for discord.py and the person who was teaching was getting pretty complicated.
He told use to create a main_cogs.py file and i did it.

This is the exact code as him:

```py
import config 
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot= bot
    
    @commands.command
    async def ping(self ,ctx):
        await ctx.send("Pong")


bot.run(config.token)
```

BTW config is a file with the token and all that stuff.

When i run it and type -ping(in chat) i get this in the console and nothing in chat:

```sh
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found
```

for him it just works.

[The video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1xESivzCPE&list=PLESMQx4LeD3NmTZ8D1qwQwwSp67kznl-K&index=7)

Thank You for the help!

Comment: try changing `self ,ctx` to `self, ctx`

Comment: Uh FBI what are you doing here! I tried that already

Comment: Is that all the code for main.py, or have you merged two files into one script? It's not apparent if you loaded the cog via `bot.add_cog` or `bot.load_extension`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb. I still am.
I DID NOT CALL THE FUNCTION!

Answer (score 1):

change
`@bot.command()` to `@commands.command()`

remove ctx from the `def __init__(self,bot,ctx):` so its `def __init__(self, bot):`

Comment: Hey , I tried it but i get 
```python
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found
```

What do i do. I have specified ping.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I use a different way of coding the bot, I'll show you my way of making a bot reply.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
bot= commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong!')

bot.run('token')
```

and my opinion on the issue? It might be because of the indented block. Since that means that that would need to trigger for that to even exist in the first place. and the missing parentheses after the `command` is also probably an issue. 100% recommend you to remove the block and add the parentheses before just trying what I made.

Comment: while this works, the person asking for help is using their code in a cog this is how you code stuff that are not in cogs.